Ortools can not evaluate LinearExpr edge case
I encounter a specific edge case in a CP model. All my variables are int based but the objective which is float based.
In a lot of usage of my model, there is no issue doing this. But in one specific instanciantion, I encounter an error while evaluating the objective.
An error is raised in the evaluation function :
# The librairie function
def evaluate_linear_expr(
    expression: LinearExprT, solution: cp_model_pb2.CpSolverResponse
) -> int:
    """Evaluate a linear expression against a solution."""
    if isinstance(expression, IntegralTypes):
        return int(expression)
    if not isinstance(expression, LinearExpr):
        raise TypeError("Cannot interpret %s as a linear expression." % expression)

    value = 0
    to_process = [(expression, 1)]
    while to_process:
        expr, coeff = to_process.pop()
        if isinstance(expr, IntegralTypes):
            value += int(expr) * coeff
        elif isinstance(expr, _ProductCst):
            to_process.append((expr.expression(), coeff * expr.coefficient()))
        elif isinstance(expr, _Sum):
            to_process.append((expr.left(), coeff))
            to_process.append((expr.right(), coeff))
        elif isinstance(expr, _SumArray):
            for e in expr.expressions():
                to_process.append((e, coeff))
            value += expr.constant() * coeff
        elif isinstance(expr, _WeightedSum):
            for e, c in zip(expr.expressions(), expr.coefficients()):
                to_process.append((e, coeff * c))
            value += expr.constant() * coeff
        elif isinstance(expr, IntVar):
            value += coeff * solution.solution[expr.index]
        elif isinstance(expr, _NotBooleanVariable):
            value += coeff * (1 - solution.solution[expr.negated().index])
        else:
            # It raises here !
            raise TypeError(f"Cannot interpret {expr} as a linear expression.")

    return value

The error: TypeError: Cannot interpret 4000000.0 as a linear expression.
Here is what I can see in debug:
> expression
(7.209805335255949e-08 * (((((((3000 * (VAR300 + (quotient + has_remainder))) + (93000 * VAR879)) + (60000 * VAR300)) + ((1500 * VAR564) + (25000 * VAR780))) + ((2000 * VAR578) + (140000 * VAR781))) + ((9570.300000000001 * VAR832) + (40000 * VAR882))) + 4000000.0))

> type(expression)
<class 'ortools.sat.python.cp_model._ProductCst'>

> type(expr)
<class 'float'>


I feel like it should be handled by the librairie... or I am doing something wrong ?
Versions Used: Python 3.9.0 ; ortools 9.11.4210
Update
I figured out that the only difference between the working instances and this one is the inclusion of a constant float offset, which the evaluation function is unable to process.
I found it inconsistant since, in any case, my objective is a floating value and is correctly handled without this constant.

a LinearExprT cannot contains a floating point value.
There is an ObjLinearExprT for that. But it has no evaluator function.

I don't really get it. Why in other instance of the model I do not encounter this?
An exemple where i can retrieve the objective value, while the value is float, expression and expr has the same structure (_ProductCst and not float) and the final value is 0.7950776712328765 (accessed by the same function : evaluate_linear_expr)

Looking at the code, it seems that + with a floating point constant will not check not cast the constant. So it depends on the formula.

But in general, this function is not meant to be used with floating point values, as it silently cast to int in many cases.

Thanks ! I didn't know that there is silent cast
